# Компьютеры не видят samba сервер

Tags: linux, samba

Компьютеры на Windows не видят samba сервер в сети, но если вводить путь к samba серверу - //UbunServer/, то доступ к расшаренным папкам есть. Вот конфиг:

```
[global]
socket options = IPTOS_LOWDELAY
workgroup = WORKGROUP
netbios name = UbunServer
server string = UbunServer
wins support = yes
password level = 8
map to guest = Bad User
null passwords = yes
use sendfile = yes
dns proxy = no

[public]
comment = Public Share
path = /home/ubun/PublicShare
public = yes
browseable = yes
guest ok = yes
writable = yes
```

Как можно сделать так, чтобы компьютеры видели samba сервер в сети?

Answer (score 3):

если рабочие станции на Windows 10, то наверняка выключен протокол *SMB1*. Следует его включить. Нажмите сочетание кнопок на клавиатуре `Win+R` и введите `appwiz.cpl`, чтобы сразу открыть *"удаление программ"*. Можете вручную через панель управления. С левой стороны нажмите на "Включение или отключение компонентов" и в новом окне появится список компонентов. Найдите *"Поддержка общего доступа к файлам SMB 1.0/CIFS"* и установите галочку, чтобы активировать и установить компонент.

Ну и в настройках *samba* в `[global]` можно поставить `min protocol = SMB1`

Comment: Если использовать min protocol = SMB2, то samba перезапускается успешно, а если min protocol = SMB1, то появляется ошибка - `Job for smbd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status smbd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details`. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: вам же пишут посмотреть `systemctl status smbd.service` и `journalctl -xe` для бОльших подробностей

Comment: Я понял, что параметра `password level` не существует, а параметр `null passwords` уже устарел. Также ошибка вызывается из-за неправильного значения `SMB1` в параметре `min protocol`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Решением оказалось добавить строку `server min protocol = NT1` в samba global

Comment: вы указывайте дистрибутив linux и версию samba. Разные сборки и разные дистры. Так проще и быстрее ответ получите